# Show 3 different values of the same column and same table in the same row in results

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server 2014 for my project. I have three tables:

```
Table A: 
Column: id
Table B:
Column: id, id_of_Table_A
Table C:
Column: id, id_of_Table_B, category

The relationship between A and B is one to many
The relationship between B and C is one to many
```

In Table C, there are 10 category values for the `category` column, but I am interested only in three categories (cat1, cat2, cat3). I hope to query and produce the following results for the three categories:

```
id_of_Table_A, category, category, category
```

I have the following statement:

```
select a.id, c.category from Table_C c 
join Table_B b on b.id = c.id_of_Table_B
join Table_A a on a.id = b.id_of_Table_A
where c.category = 'cat1' and a.id in (1, 2, 3)
```

But this statement only lists

```
id_of_Table_A, cat1
```

which contains only cat1 of a given id_of_Table_A. I hope to have something like:

```
1, cat1, cat2, cat3
```

if cat1, cat2, and cat3 exists in Table C for the given id `1` in Table A.

If a single statement is unable to produce the desired results, then a stored procedure is okay.

**Update**

In the following example results,

```
1, cat1, cat2, cat3
```

cat1, cat2, cat3 must come from three different records in Table B. Suppose we have these tables and rows:

```
Table A: 1,2
Table B: (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2), (5,2), (6,2)
Table c: (1,1,'cat3'), (2,2,'cat1'), (3,3,'cat2'), (4,4,'cat1'), (5,5,'cat4'), (6,6,'cat2')
```

Then the expected results should be:

```
1, cat1, cat2, cat3
```

Basically, the relationships of the tables form a tree. I hope to find the root  (Table A) with leaves being cat1, cat2, and cat3 on non-overlapping paths from the root.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: `where c.category = 'cat1'` means you are only interested in `cat1`.

Comment: That is just an example. I am unable to write the query to produce cat2  and cat3 in results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine all categories for `id_of_b` in a single `xml` value and then show categories in columns. Something like this.

```
declare @a table(id int)
declare @b table(id int,id_of_a int)
declare @c table(id int,id_of_b int,category varchar(50))
insert @a values(1),(2)
insert @b values(1,1),(2,1),(3,2)
insert @c values(1,1,'cat1'),(2,1,'cat2'),(3,1,'cat3'),(4,2,'cat4')
;with cte as(
  select a.id,
    cast((select category from @c c where c.id_of_b = b.id for xml auto,root,type) as xml) xcat
  from @a a inner join @b b on a.id = b.id_of_a
)
select id,
  t.v.value('c[1]/@category','varchar(50)') cat1,
  t.v.value('c[2]/@category','varchar(50)') cat2,
  t.v.value('c[3]/@category','varchar(50)') cat3
from cte
cross apply xcat.nodes('root') t(v)
```

**Updated answer for updated question**

```
declare @a table(id int)
declare @b table(id int,id_of_a int)
declare @c table(id int,id_of_b int,category varchar(50))
insert @a values(1),(2)
insert @b values (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2), (5,2), (6,2)
insert @c values (1,1,'cat3'), (2,2,'cat1'), (3,3,'cat2'), (4,4,'cat1'), (5,5,'cat4'), (6,6,'cat2')

;with cte as(
  select a.id,
    cast((select category from @c c inner join @b b on c.id_of_b = b.id 
       where b.id_of_a=a.id
       for xml auto,root,type) as xml) xcat
  from @a a 
)
select id,
  t.v.value('c[1]/@category','varchar(50)') cat1,
  t.v.value('c[2]/@category','varchar(50)') cat2,
  t.v.value('c[3]/@category','varchar(50)') cat3
from cte
cross apply xcat.nodes('root') t(v)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, there seems a syntax error for `;with cte as...`. The Management Studio indicates there is an error.

Comment: Still got error message in Management Studio. Syntax error.

Comment: what is the message?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14.Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Thanks for the update.The example is working, but the results are not what I expected. I am sorry about the post not being clear enough. Please see my updated post.

Comment: Alex, I never used the approach you proposed. Quick question: how is its performance in case of a large table (millions of records)?